# Changing vee-validate error messages for 'date_format', 'after' or 'before'

Tags: validation, momentjs, vuejs2

I'm trying to change the error messages generated by vee-validate for functions that utilize the momement.js library. I am able to change the messages for other validation rules, such as 'required', but not for 'date_format', 'before' or 'after'. Is this because those rules use the moment.js library? Is there any way to change those error messages?

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate,{
  fieldsBagName: 'vFields',
  dictionary: {
    en: {
      messages: {
        required: 'Your field is empty', // messages can be strings as well.
        date_format: 'wrong format for date',
        after:"date is too old",
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
        alert('Is valid')
      }).catch(() => {
        alert('Is not valid')
      })
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brose/qodz7cL3/)

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this using the following code inside my component:

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
const dictionary = {
    en: {
        messages: {
            after: (field, args) => `The ${field} must be greater than ${moment(args, moment.defaultFormat).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}.`,
            date_format: (field, args) => `The ${field} is invalid.`
        }
    }
}

VeeValidate.Validator.updateDictionary(dictionary);
```